# Brussels to Les Arcs for skiing, other than by car?

Tags: air-travel, public-transport, france, brussels

I would like to go skiing in Les Arcs this winter.

1. How can I get there from Belgium using public transport? Should I fly to Geneva? Take the Thalys or TGV? I don't want to rent a car.
2. Is it a beginner-friendly resort? Are there easy routes and ski lessons? My partner is an absolute beginner, but I can find no information online.

Comment: As per the [help center](http://travel.stackexchange.com/help), this would really be better as two independent questions - travel + beginner-friendly-ness

Comment: les arcs is kind of car-oriented.  to take the train, i guess you'd go to bourg-st-maurice.  then there's that funicular.  it also depends "which" les arcs you want to go to.  (2000, etc.)  to fly, sure, just geneve and then a long long long bus ride.  (I guess lyon or chambery are officially closer but again it's just a really long bus ride.)  going back to the train, trains to/from bourg-st-maurice basically go to **Chambery**.  (grab the SNCF app, go to that station, and you can see the arrival/departure boards).

Comment: @JoeBlow are you kidding? Les Arcs is probably the ski resort the best served by public transportation in France. There are TGVs arriving in Bourg-St-Maurice from Paris and regional trains from Lyon, and a funicular going directly up there.

Comment: Hey Vince - yeah, I guess you're right  :)  I just like my car! :) You know you make a good question "which french station is best served by train?"  I guess it is indeed Bourg-St-Maurice!  (chamonix is kind of cheating that's a city.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note - as Vince importantly pointed out, Les Arcs (gare == bourg-st-maurice) is perhaps the French ski station which is best-served by train!

---

For the record, I just clicked here http://www.voyages-sncf.com and entered "Bruxelles" "Bourg Saint Maurice"

There are a number of connections of about 7-8 hours, generally via Lyon.

Or you could fly to Chambery then train. But it's a nuisance to get from chambery airport to the chambery train station.

If you don't mind the incredibly long bus ride, probably just fly to Genève.

Finally consider "which" Les Arcs you are going to (1800, 2000 etc).